# Returning the subtype used when extension function is set on supertype

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am creating a kotlin rest controller where I want different collections subtypes to be returned with different calls. I also have a Dao object I want to map to a Dto to send to the client.

I therefore have the extension function

```
private fun Collection<Dao>.toDto(): Collection<Dto> {
    return this.map { dao -> Dto.convertToDto(dao) }
}
```

However this will return a `Collection<Dto>` regardless of the collection type this is used on. I.e, what is **actually happening** is

```
Set<Dao>.toDto() -> Collection<Dto>
List<Dao>.toDto() -> Collection<Dto>
```

The **desired result** would be

```
Set<Dao>.toDto() -> Set<Dto>
List<Dao>.toDto() -> List<Dto>
```

So question is two-part.

1. How do I go about achieving this?
2. is this acceptable already? I reckon the Set/List functionality will already be implemented, unsure if collection maintains the order of the list, also this is unclear for any developers interacting against the API as to the intention of the API, that you get an ordered list, or set, etc. If it is not dangerous/bad practice I could accept this.

Comment: I guess you would have to create multiple extension functions for the different subclass of Collection you want to use.

Comment: That is fine for my use-case. I imagine if you have a large number of subtypes you care about that would not be a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Function signature should be something like `private fun <T : Collection<*>> T<Dao>.toDto(): T<Dto>`, but that syntax is impossible in Kotlin, cause `Type arguments are not allowed for type parameters` (it's forbidden in Java as well, by the way). But even if it was possible, `map` method always returns `List` (preserving original order), regardless of original collection type, so you would have to convert it back to original collection subtype, and there is no way to do it in general case.